# wp site is very slow

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I have createe a **WordPress Woocommerce Website**, and everything is working normally, but it is very very slow!

This is the url: https://www.mycubeapp.com

According to [this report](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.mycubeapp.com/34MiQdid) the load time is  17.8 seconds.
I want to make it load more quickly, but I don't know how.

As you can see from gtmetrix.com I have problems with **'Add Expires headers'** and **'Avoid landing page redirects'** but i don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The image in your slider is 13.4M. Worse, it reloads every time the slider changes and takes an average of 8.4s to load. You should reduce the image size and make sure caching is enabled. If you can post a little bit about what slider you're using and what caching plugin, I can help you with the settings.